# Flutter Firebase Dynamic Links Weird Behaviour

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

This is a iOS only problem.

I have set up firebase dynamic links (using the console) to open a specific page if the user has the app installed and open the app store if they dont.

If the user has the app installed then the deep link works as expected.

If they do not have the app installed they get presented [with this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3igq.png)

The app is a UK app and the picture is me trying to open it. ~

Just to reiterate: this ONLY happens on iOS and ONLY if the app is not installed. Android works as expected. The app bundle IDs are correctly linked because I am still receiving events and when the app is installed it opens the deeplink correctly.

Comment: Do you have the applications's AppStore identifier in the dynamic link as well? It is the `isi` parameter.